# update kivy ever few seconds

Tags: python, kivy, spotipy

**I'm trying to make a Spotify app using kivy and spotipy, I got it to display the album work and info of what's currently playing, but I want it to refresh so it updates when the song changes. is this possible?
here is my code if anyone can help. **

```
try:
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)
except (AttributeError, JSONDecodeError):
    os.remove(f".cache-{username}")
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri) # add scope

# Create our spotify object with permissions
spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)



# Current track information

track = spotifyObject.current_user_playing_track()
if track != None:
    artist = track['item']['artists'][0]['name']
    playing = track['item']['name']



#define image
################################################################################
link = (track['item']['album']['images'][0]['url'])
response = requests.get(link)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img.thumbnail((300,300))
img.save("img1.jpg")

#Create kivy GUI
################################################################################
class Page(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Page, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.image = 'img1.jpg'
        self.track = playing
        self.artist = artist




#load kivy app
################################################################################

class HomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("home.kv" )

        return Page()



HomeApp().run()
```

Comment: If you want to run some code repeatedly, use Clock.schedule_interval.